# Immediate Window constructor "Type 'class name' is not defined." issue

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, immediate-window

I am having issues testing classes/functions with Visual Studio 2013 Immediate Window.

If I test my constructor in the Immediate Window-

> test = new Config()

I get..

> "Type 'Config' is not defined."

if I test a public function inside the Config class in the Immediate Window-

> ?GetConfigFromDatabase()

I get..

> 'GetConfigFromDatabase' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.'

The pseudo code for what I am testing is..

```
Friend Class Config
'Constructors and Destructors
Public Sub New()
    GetConfigFromDatabase()
End Sub


'Public Methods 
Public Function GetConfigFromDatabase() As Boolean
    '----Function stuff here
End Function

End Class
```

I am not sure what simple thing I am doing wrong. I have tried a clean solution with rebuild, closing and reopening VS, but always the same thing. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: the second wont work because `GetConfigFromDatabase` can only be invoked using and object reference.  the first would seem to be a matter of scope.  Why not try/test in a button click event?

Comment: It can guess at a default namespace but that depends on which breakpoint is active.  If you are not debugging or are stopped in the wrong code then you must use the full type name.